# Replace specific "var" in string

Tags: python-3.x

i have a string with several "" in it, i need to replace a specific one.
but this is not working, can anyone tell, me how to do this?

tried this

```
jsdump = jsdump.replace('"var"', card_var).strip()
jsdump = jsdump.replace("""var""", card_var).strip()
```

and nothing.

this is what i need:

card_var = cd1

basicly have: "in sentence","where "var" is ok"

need to replace to: "in sentence","where cd1 is ok"

Comment: The question is unclear. I suggest reformulating it including the current and wished behavior. For your problem try to use regex (`import re`) and create a dictionary with the words you want to replace: `replacement_dict["var"]="cd1"`

Comment: what dont you understand, maybe i can explain better, i need to replace a var in a string, the problem is that that var has "" so its dificult to build the replacement statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I had in mind writing my comment:

```
import re
mystr = '"in sentence","where "var" is ok"'

replacement_dict = {"var": "cd1"}    # add other replacements to the dict following your needs
print(re.sub(r'"(\w+)"', lambda x: replacement_dict.get(x.group(1), x.group()) , mystr))
```

We replace the elements found in the dictionary (quotes are then removed) and let unchanged (quotes stay) if not in dictionary.

Comment: thanks, will keep this for reference.   in the meanwhile this jsdump = jsdump.replace('"var"', card_var).strip() started working fine :s